# Faltando privilégios na lista de privilégios

Tags: debate, bug, privilégios

Na lista de privilégios não está listado os privilégios de analisar `Publicações de baixa qualidade` nem `Edições sugeridas`. A reputação necessária é de 1000.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, olhando no SO.com percebi que esses privilégios também não estão listados lá.

Existe algum motivo para eles não estarem listados?

Não seria conveniente mostrá-los assim como é feito com os privilégios de `acessar as filas de análise` e `atribuir votos encerrados e reabertos` ?